# JavaScript renders replicated text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I' am working on a project where its sidebar menu's last word in a menu title has to be a different color (Blue). Just because the sidebar menu is automatically generated by WordPress I had no choice but to be JavaScript to add a class onto the last word.

**HTML**

```
<li class="page_item page-item-191">
  <a href="http://www.developers.4fj.com/get-involved/our-pledgers/">Our Pledgers</a>
</li>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var txt = $(".page-item-191 a").text();
var splitted = txt.split(" ");
var lastWord = splitted.pop();
var newTxt = splitted.join(" ") + "<span class='color1'> " + lastWord + "</span>";
$(".page-item-191 a").html(newTxt);
```

**The Problem**
When I run this code I' am getting

> Take The PledgeTake the Pledge

Whereas I should only been getting back from JavaScript is `

> Take The  Pledge

What's wrong what am I missing? Thanks!

`

Comment: it works for me. http://jsbin.com/yuneledu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: You should show how/when/where your code is executed.